Adding a variable as part of a data source URL in grafana
I want to integrate a map of the XYZ tile layer type from a website. The url of the map changes based on the current date.
As a naive first attempt, I replaced (part of) the URL with a dashboard variable:
URL template:
https://some-api.com/$mydate_variable/{z}/{x}/{y}

This doesn't work.
The same thing works if I replace $mydate_variable with the date string (i.e. 20240416).
In the variable overview of the dashboard I can see that grafana recognizes that the variable is being used in the panel.
I also noticed that the same thing happens when I try to import an image in a HTML panel. Hard-coded link works fine, link with variable doesn't.
I think this might have to do with the $ character being URL encoded but I don't know how to solve the issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try such syntax:
${mydate_variable}

URL template will be the following:
https://some-api.com/${mydate_variable}/{z}/{x}/{y}

